# How to dynamically change the value of the <a> 'download' field in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following:

```
        AUTHOR<input type="text" name="author" id="authortxt"><br>
        FILENAME<input type="text" name="filename" id="filenametxt"><br>
        EMAIL<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        <img id="saveicon" src="interface/SaveIcon0.png" onmouseover="this.src='./interface/SaveIcon1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='./interface/SaveIcon0.png'" />
        <img id="cancelicon" src="interface/CancelIcon0.png" onmouseover="this.src='./interface/CancelIcon1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='./interface/CancelIcon0.png'" />
        <a id="download" download="TestJSON-r.json">Download</a>
```

I need the filename of the download to be set by the 'FILENAME' field. What is the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) over respective elements to accomplish your task,

```
$("#download").attr("download", $("#filenametext").val())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jquery you simply use plain Javascript. here is the code.

```
    AUTHOR<input type="text" name="author" id="authortxt"><br>
   AUTHOR<input type="text" name="author" id="authortxt"><br>
    FILENAME<input type="text" name="filename" id="filenametxt"  onchange="change_download_text(this)"><br>
    EMAIL<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <img id="saveicon" src="interface/SaveIcon0.png" onmouseover="this.src='./interface/SaveIcon1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='./interface/SaveIcon0.png'" />
    <img id="cancelicon" src="interface/CancelIcon0.png" onmouseover="this.src='./interface/CancelIcon1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='./interface/CancelIcon0.png'" />
    <a id="download" download="TestJSON-r.json">Download</a>

     <script>
        function change_download_text(calledvalue){
        var download =  document.getElementById("download") ; 
        download.innerHTML = calledvalue.value ;
      }
    </script>
```